# Access - Counting / occurrence query and returning a percentage Pie Chart

Tags: ms-access

I'm looking for some help collating data into a pie chart in Microsoft Access.

I have a list of staff training with refresher dates in a table - Staff Training

I have 3 separate queries that pull  out

In Date Training
Out of Date Training
Training with no date added

I need to count how many rows are in each and then combine this data into a pie chart to show what % is "In Date", "Out of Date" and "No Date".

My 3 queries work and I have a count at the bottom of each giving me the relevant numbers. I just cant work out how to access this number and pull into a pie chart.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT [Staff Training].[Staff Member], [Staff Training].ID, 
[Staff Training].Area, [Staff Training].Course, [Staff Training].[Refresher Date]
FROM [Staff Training]
WHERE ((([Staff Training].[Refresher Date])<=Now()));

SELECT [Staff Training].ID, [Staff Training].[Staff Member], 
[Staff Training].Area, [Staff Training].Course, [Staff Training].[Refresher Date]
FROM [Staff Training]
WHERE ((([Staff Training].[Refresher Date])>Now()));

SELECT [Staff Training].ID, [Staff Training].Area, [Staff Training].Course,
[Staff Training].[Refresher Date], [Staff Training].[Staff Member]
FROM [Staff Training]
WHERE ((([Staff Training].[Refresher Date]) Is Null));
```

Data format:

[Data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjH5l.png)

Comment: Possibly with a UNION query. Or perhaps even 1 aggregate query instead of 3. Edit question to show sample raw data.

Comment: Thanks @June7 I have updated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  IIf ( ([Staff Training].[Refresher Date]) Is Null ,0 , IIf ( ([Staff Training].[Refresher Date])<=Now() ,1, 2) )    FROM [Staff Training]
```

or

```
SELECT  IIf ([Staff Training].[Refresher Date] Is Null ,"Training with no date added" , IIf ( [Staff Training].[Refresher Date]<=Now() ,"In Date Training", "Out of Date Training"))    FROM [Staff Training]
```

and make the following Query1 based on the above result

```
SELECT Query1.Field1, Count(Query1.Field1)/(select count(*) from Query1) *100 AS percentage  FROM Query1 GROUP BY Query1.Field1
```

Comment: would this be 4 separate queries?

Comment: So i would then need this to count the 1, 2 & 3 to give me a % of all equating to 100%

Comment: Hi @ywwy sorry im a bit of a noob with access. Im struggling with the Select Count()

Comment: Did the first suggested query work ? If yes, then the easiest way is to make a new query based on that one. SELECT Count(Query1.field1)/Sum(Query1.field1) AS Percentage FROM Query1 GROUP BY (Query1.field1)

Comment: Thanks @ywwy this returns:

#Div/0!
1
0.5

Comment: i changed it from 0 1 2 to 1 2 3 which solved the Div. This however doesn't look right. Do I need to count and sum?

Comment: You are right, sum does not work, I updated my answer with something that should.

Comment: Thanks @Ywwy thats it all sorted and working now. Really appreciate the help.